# Magento 2 : Create cms block store vise with same identifier

Tags: magento2, cms-block, cms-pages

I want to create CMS block with same identifier. **For ex.**  Testing is my identifier. But, content of testing is different in German store view and Russia store view.

How to create store vise CMS block with same identifier ?

Please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes that's possible by default. If you have multiple stores then by default when you create a block it will opt an option called multiple stores

Comment: It will store content in same id. But, I want like when I store switch then it will display that store content.

Comment: I found from where I can able to do that. vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php ....  function getIsUniqueBlockToStores()

Comment: if (!$isDefaultStore) {
   // $select->where('cbs.store_id IN (?)', $stores);
  }
I need to comment this code and add this line $select->where('cbs.store_id = ' . $stores[0]); But how to override or by plugin? Is it possible?